# Can I write some initial data on a EM4100 rfid card?

Tags: nfc, rfid

I understand that the EM4100 cards contain only read-only data, and no new data can be written to it. So my question is: who writes the initial data? Is it like a cd (write once) or does it have some kind of id/code on it when you buy it?

Thanks!
Tekin.

Answer (score 1):

EM4100 is normally read only chip (chip spec on http://www.mikroe.com/download/eng/documents/development-tools/components/em4100_datasheet.pdf).
You have to order the good programming from your manufacturer/reseller and it will be done on the factory.

Depending on your use case, you can also purchase EM4100-like chip which behave just like these (in read at least) but are R&W with appropriate hardware.